# 8GB USB pen drive showing 700MB after formatting

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

My 8GB pen drive is now showing 700MB after I formatted it. I've created Ubuntu Desktop bootable USB drive using Power ISO.

After I formatted it. Now it's showing 700MB. Why is that? I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: does it show same space on ubuntu?,check this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/68809/how-to-format-a-usb-or-external-drive

Comment: Also related: [16 GB USB flash drive capacity down to 938 MB](//superuser.com/q/752874/354511), [Flash disk capacity turns from 32 GB to 4 MB](//superuser.com/q/937410/354511), [USB drive not showing full size](//superuser.com/q/88509/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive shows as 16 MB and is unusable](//superuser.com/q/50207/354511), [1 GB space left after formatting a 16 GB flash drive?](/q/339489/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive turned to 1 GB after writing an ISO image onto it](/q/759602/354511) and [Toshiba pen drive shows 4 MB instead of 8 GB; what could have happened to it?](/q/927680/354511)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you only formatted than one partition that got created for your bootable Ubuntu Desktop.

In order to resolve this you might want to use "Disk Management" (see http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disk-management-windows-7.htm how to find it), delete existing partitions on your USB drive and create a new one, filling all the space.

Afterwards, format it according to your file system needs.

Beware, all your information that's stored on the usb drive up to now, will be lost.

Answer (score -1):

Open command line (cmd) and type `diskpart`. Allow the windows to run it.

Type `list disk`, and find the number of your USB flash disk.

Type `select disk X`, and type the number of the USB disk instead of X. It should say that "disk X is now selected".

Type `clean`.

Type `create partition primary`.